# PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

Tags: nginx, debian, php-fpm, wordpress, upload

I have exported a WordPress XML file which contain all pages, posts, WooCommerce products, orders etc. File size is 100MB. Now I am trying to import it on another machine but getting error. It even shows that allowed file size is 200MB. This is a 1GB RAM, 1 Core VPS.

[image]

But I am getting following error:

> [error] 3811#3811: *10 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal
> error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to
> allocate 20480 bytes) in
> /var/www/stackoverflow.com/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-importer/parsers/class-wxr-parser-simplexml.php
> on line 211; PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of
> 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in
> /var/www/stackoverflow.com/wp-includes/error-protection.php on line
> 48"

This is despite the fact that that I am using following limits.

**wp-config.php**

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/stackoverflow**

```
server
{
    client_max_body_size    200M;
}
```

**/etc/php/8.2/fpm/php.ini**

```
post_max_size           200M
upload_max_filesize     200M
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Considered a higher limit amount in `wp-config.php`? `268435456 bytes` is `256M` pretty much exactly...

Comment: `post_max_size` & `upload_max_filesize` aren't related to this error, but increasing them may cause more of these errors.